# Minimum target iOS version for games

Tags: ios, appstore

I have noticed lately on the App Store many games have been updated to require a minimum of iOS 4.3 to run thus eliminating support for 2nd gen devices (iPod Touch 2nd gen and iPhone 3G).

It is now 2013, my question is what should be the minimum target iOS version and device platform for games development. If it is 4.3+ why not support older devices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While there is no minimum version you have to support, starting from May 1, 2013, all apps [*must* support](https://developer.apple.com/news/index.php?id=3212013b) retina display and iPhone 5 screen size.

Specially in the iOS ecosystem, you may suppose all users are running under the latest iOS version, so making your game run only on iOS 6 and above will probably get you a large proportion of users (and the vast majority of those who would pay for your game). Supporting iOS 5 will virtually get you every user.

Comment: I guess you could still support non-retina display devices while supporting retina display deives at the same time?

Comment: @JamesEldridge Sure, but usually supporting retina display is an additional element, so by supporting retina displays you're automatically supporting non-retina displays. Specifically, retina displays don't appear as having a greater resolution, but as having twice the pixel density. This means that you don't have to do coordinate changes when writing for retina displays, simply enable retina support.

Answer (score 1):

Apple dropped the support for Arm v6 in Xcode 4.5, so you pretty much can't make games for iPhone 1, 3g and some of the early iPod touches.

Comment: Thanks for the elaboration. It is kind of annoying if you have an old device and reset it to factory default, no more apps!